# JAX-WS vs Restlet Framework for Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, restlet

Which is the better options? Pros and cons of each? The web services are meant to be internal-facing and are all going to be roughly in the same datacenter (3-4km apart at most). Any ideas?

Some criteria that would make one better than the other include: ease of setup, maintainable code, stable API and ability to be implemented in legacy Java code. Of course performance is also a concern but not as major because the latency should be rather small.

Comment: Please define your criteria for "better".  Almost anything could be counted as better: Faster, Cheaper, Full Employment, Reliance on XML, anything.  Please pick some things that would be "better" in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also to consider [Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/)

We are using this framework. It's got a good unit tests package, great examples, and it's easy to deploy.